# Python - Filling an array with calculated values

Tags: python

I have a function defined as: def f2(x) in my code and I want to get a list of x and y values for that function. Here is my code to do this:

```
     x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
     print("\nx values:\n ", x)

     f2y = np.zeros(len(x))
     # print("f2y, empty array of y values: ", f2y)

     for i in range(0, len(x), 1):
        for j in x:
            f2y[i] = f2(j)
```

The f2y array is supposed to fill up with different y-values based on what x value is plugged in. However, the f2y array gets the same value in its array.

Comment: Why don't you just use a list comprehension? 

`f2y = [f2(j) for j in x]`

Comment: Why are you using a nested for loop to fill the information? The `for i in range(0, len(x), 1)` seems unnecessary.

Comment: Thank you! Your solutions worked to perfection.

Comment: If the f2 is a lambda or a function that applies calculations to a variable, it might be possible to apply that function to the entire array without a loop. See my answer for clarification.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correct, you need something like this:

```
 import numpy as np
 x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)
 #print("\nx values:\n ", x)
 #print len(x)

 f2y = np.zeros(len(x))
 #print("f2y, empty array of y values: ", f2y)
 #print len(f2y)
 f2y = [i for i in x]
 print f2y
```

Answer (score 0):

Go ahead and try this out.

```
# declare a list of x values
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, 100)

# define a function to apply to the x values
f2 = lambda i: i**2

# calculate our y values
f2y = f2(x)
```